# Unfortunately app has stopped in webview using eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview

I was using webview for creating an app. When i run the code it shows

> Unfortunately app_name has stopped

I referred to many answers in stackoverflow, but none of them working for me. I even tried installing the same app in mobile, it is giving the same error.

Please refer  the below codes.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.webception.demoappview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private WebView webView;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        }

    }
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.webception.demoappview.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webception.demoappview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidwebviewexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<activity 
        android:name="com.example.androidwebviewexample.WebActivity">
    </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have less knowledge of java so a working solution is appreciated.

Comment: `MainActivity` Activity is in `com.webception.demoappview` package instead of `com.example.androidwebviewexample` so use `.MainActivity` or `com.webception.demoappview.MainActivity` for adding Activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your xml name is wrong:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Replace activity_main by your xml fragment_main.

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

And also change `MainActivity` package name in manifest.

Replace

```
com.example.androidwebviewexample.MainActivity
```

To

```
com.webception.demoappview.MainActivity
```

Comment: thank you for the help. but getting same error still.

Comment: In your xml change  tools:context=".MainActivity" in parent layout.

Comment: thank you. i changed com.example.androidwebviewexample.MainActivity to com.webception.demoappview.MainActivity . its not giving any error. output is blank. That's because emulator cannot connect to internet i guess.